# Proper URI path for views render array

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to Drupal and Drupalgap.

My Drupal site has a view/content called "donations".

In admin/structure/views, there are two PATHs: /current-donations and /available-donations.  And of course, this URL works fine: http://127.0.0.1:8083/current-donations

Now I'd like to render this view in drupalgap using a views render array.

My first attempt looked like:

```
function mobile_donor_donations_page() {
try {
    console.log('mobile_donor_donations_list_page()-e');
    var content = {};
    content['avail_donations_list'] = {
        theme: 'view',
        format: 'ul',
        path: '/available-donations', /* the path to the view in Drupal */
        row_callback: 'mobile_donor_donations_list_row',
        empty_callback: 'mobile_donor_donations_list_empty',
        attributes: {
            id: 'avail_donations_list_view'
        }
    };
    return content;
}
catch (error) { console.log(':ER:mobile_donor_donations_page: ' + error); };
}
```

The above function gets called fine -- on my console (chrome, Ripple) I see

```
GET: http://127.0.0.1:8083/?q=/available-donations&page=0
200 - OK
views_embed_view - success - TypeError: Cannot read    property 'count' of undefined
```

Looking at the views_embed_view() code below, it is throwing an exception
because results.view is undefined:

```
// Render the view if there are some results, or if there are no results and an
// empty_callback has been specified. Otherwise remove the empty div container for
// the view from the DOM.
if (results.view.count != 0 || results.view.count == 0 && options.empty_callback) {
```

I tried http://127.0.0.1:8083/?q=/available-donations&page=0 from my
browser, it returns html, not JSON.

To force JSON returned, I tried

```
path: 'drupalgap/node.json&parameters[type]=donation', /* the path to the view in Drupal */
```

This PATH does indeed return my content as JSON, however the error remains, 
since the JSON doesn't contain a "view" element.

```
GET: http://127.0.0.1:8083/?q=drupalgap/node.json&parameters[type]=donation&page=0
200 - OK
views_embed_view - success - TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined
```

What PATH do I need to supply, or do I need to change structure of my content in Drupal to get the view to render?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you create a `JSON Data Document` display in your View, then give it a page path? That is the `path` that you use when building the Views Render Array.

Comment: No, I was using the original view for the Drupal site.   I followed your instructions below and created a new view with format "JSON data document" with path http://127.0.0.1:8083/my-donations.json.  This works great and I see the "count" element which was missing before.  

http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/build-mobile-app-geo-locate-content-drupal

Comment: Great, I'm glad it is working. Please accept the answer when you have a moment, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to create a `JSON Data Document` display for your View with a unique page path, then you can use that `path` in your DrupalGap Views Render Array. More documentation and examples are available here: http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Views/Displaying_a_View/Views_Render_Array